# Akka.net restart actor system termination on node quarentined

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

We are developing a cluster with Akka.net v1.4.38 on we have seed nodes that communicate with a external system using Akka.IO.TCP, and multiple client nodes that receive and send messages to seed nodes. If a client node lost communication with the cluster we need to restart the Akka actor system on this node because is quarentined. We created a Actor that listen AssociationErrorEvent and ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent and restart the system when receive this messages.

```
public class ErrorManagerActor: ReceiveActor {
    public ErrorManagerActor(Action action) {
        Receive<ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent>(m => {
            action();
        });
        Receive<AssociationErrorEvent>(m => {
            action();
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the actor system never stop and show a warning in console:

> [CoordinatedShutdown (akka://xxxxx)] Coordinated shutdown phase
> [actor-system-terminate] timed out after 00:00:10

We created a UnitTest to reproduce the problem.

```
    [Test]
    public void TerminateSystemTest() {
        var actor = Sys.ActorOf(Props.Create<ErrorManagerActor>(() => {
            if (!Sys.Terminate().Wait(10000))
                Assert.Fail("Unable to terminate actor system");
            terminatedEvent.Set();
        }));
        Sys.EventStream.Subscribe(actor, typeof(AssociationErrorEvent));
        Sys.EventStream.Subscribe(actor, typeof(ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent));
        var cluster = Cluster.Get(Sys);
        Sys.EventStream.Publish(new ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent(cluster.SelfAddress, cluster.SelfAddress));
        terminatedEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your test fails is that in order for the `ActorSystem` to terminate it has to kill all actors first, *including* the one running your test assertion. So having an actor execute a blocking `Task.Wait` on `System.Terminate` will result in a deadlock.

To fix this in a production system, *just don't wait* on the `Task`.

Comment: I modified the call to action() inside ErrorManagerActor as follows, and the test result is Ok:

`Context.Self.GracefulStop(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ContinueWith(x => action());`  

thanks!